# Android Application Not Storing Key Value Pair in Firebase Database

Tags: android, database, firebase

I have a registration system that stores user information in Firebase database. One of the key is not getting stored, the password key. Before storing the password I'm hashing the password through md5 (just for testing purposes) don't jump on me telling me md5 is not secure and I shouldn't store it in this way. I know!... (testing). Anyway, I'm able to store all user info: full name, email, phone etc... but password doesn't get stored. Before sending to firebase, I create my user in the form of `User user = new User(val1, val2, val3)` 
then I use user.set to set all other values. all get store in firebase except password. Why? Thanks

```
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //insert data into firebase database
        if(usernameEditText.getText() != null && nameEditText.getText() != null &&
            emailEditText.getText() != null) {
            username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
            fname = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            password = HashPassword.getMd5(passwordEditText.getText().toString());
            Log.d("PASSWORD", password);
            User user = new User(username, fname, email);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setPhone(phoneEditText.getText().toString());
            user.setProfession(professionEditText.getText().toString());
            user.setWorkplace(workEditText.getText().toString());
            mDatabase.child(username).setValue(user);
            //send back to login page after user complete registration
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
        }
    }
});
```

User class

```
package org.techgeorge.loginscreen;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * user class to keep track of registered user
 * and their data (profile info)
 */

public class User {

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String fullName;
    private String profession;
    private String workplace;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    private String sex;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String fullName, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSex() { return sex; }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public void setWorkplace(String wordplace) {
        this.workplace = wordplace;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public String getWorkplace() {
        return workplace;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) { this.sex = sex; }

}
```

Comment: Show us the content of your `User` class.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using the firebase authentication system?

Comment: Firebase doesn't care what you are storing and how you named it, there is no magic. To check this, rename the password to anything safe to be stored unsecured. Check the way you send data. Find the diff of passing email and password.

Comment: @RevakoOA what is the proper way to store data? does everything stored in User class gets send to firebase database. or does it have to be in the constructor

Comment: @miatech, I don't know. There is the answer by Pratyush I'm always using. It's a rule of thumb. Very easy to change the saving destination, debug. Push the data as JSON e.g., and such you explicitly set which data will go to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this :

Add this getAsJson(); in user class

```
public HashMap<String, Object> getAsMap(){
        HashMap<String, Object> userAsMap = new HashMap<>();
        userAsMap.put("username",username);
        userAsMap.put("password",password);
        userAsMap.put("age",age);
        userAsMap.put("name",name);

        //Add or remove more key value pair

        return userAsMap;
    }
```

And replace your setvalue(user) to setvalue (user.getAsMap());